# Random riddles (trying my hand)

Tags: riddle

Trying my hand at creating these, let me know what you think. These are 3 different riddles.

-

```
I have 4 legs
And I make a great meal
But it’s when I show facts
That I seal the deal
```

-

```
If you’re angry and you shouted 
Line up straight so you’ll be counted
If you’re lightning on the water
Then your skills will soon be touted
```

-

```
Get away from me he said
You scoffed the bun I planned to eat
But I won't get very far
With nothing on my feet
```

Comment: Are these 3 different riddles or one single riddle?

Comment: 3 different, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I have 4 legs, And I make a great meal

> a **table** has four legs and supports a meal

But it’s when I show facts, That I seal the deal

> tables are used to display facts for business reports

2) If you’re angry and you shouted

> **row** - dispute loudly

Line up straight so you’ll be counted

> a row is a sequence of items

If you’re lightning on the water. Then your skills will soon be touted

> to row is to oar along a river, if fast then noted

3) Get away from me he said

> *shoo* off means go away

You scoffed the bun I planned to eat

> *choux* (sc)off, perhaps, the choux pastry is gone

But I won't get very far, With nothing on my feet

> *shoe*(s) off - have taken your footwear off

Feedback: One and two are fine, not sure about three, and usually one question is asked.